# what means a type like SomeType<T, U, V> in typescript?

Tags: typescript, d3.js, typescript-generics

I'm using d3 with typescript and there is a lot of types in d3 that are like this `SomeType<U,T,V>`. Example:

```
merge(other: Selection<GElement, Datum, PElement, PDatum>): Selection<GElement, Datum, PElement, PDatum>
```

I looked through the advanced types documentation but could not understand what these types mean. I can't say if they are a Selection type with these subtypes or whatever.

Comment: Are you asking about the concept of [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html)? Or about something specific to how d3 uses them?

Comment: I thought generics could only be used with functions and classes, I wasn't seeing those as if they where generics, but it looks very clear now that they are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are generics. And put simply they let you parameterize a type, allowing you pass other types into it.

So to use your example, you could do something like:

```
interface SomeType<T, U, V> {
  t: T
  u: U
  v: V
}

const foo: SomeType<string, number, { cool: boolean }> = {
  //                T       U       V
  t: 'a string',
  u: 123,
  v: { cool: true }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoHsC2EAqBPABwgB4cAaZAVQoDUA+ZAbwChlkwAuZHV5AVy6VeANy41mAX2bME6EAGcwyGOnRcM2fEWKKooAOYUQfTACNoFRslnoANl1OrbEOCGQSGAXia9OyAORwyLoG-mS8AsgAjABMAMzhbKJM1k5cYFB8KFISQA)

Lots of documentation on generics here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

Comment: I thought generics could only be used with functions and classes, I did not realize that I could build the types with them and put them in the function arguments. Thank you.

Comment: This answer can help to know why: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68458263/7543637

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure on typescript, but at least on some other languages such as C# the T type is a Generic Type Parameter basically it means that you dont need to specify a concrete type of object.