# Why do we use the letters T, U in TypeScript Generics

Tags: typescript, naming-conventions, typescript-generics, identifier

I noticed most tutorials/courses/articles use `T`, `U`... as the name of generic types. Why exactly, why not assign normal names instead?

Comment: And what would be a "normal name" for something for a can take any kind of value and is supposed to be neutral to what can that be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a convention; different kinds of things have visibly different name formats so you can tell what kind of thing something is from what format its name is written in. For example, in Java, Javascript and Typescript it's conventional to use `camelCase` for variables and method names, `UpperCamelCase` for class names, and `UPPER_SNAKE_CASE` for constants; and it's conventional to use `T` for a type parameter.

This way, if you see a type named `T` you know it is a type parameter, whereas if you see a type named `Person` you know it's not. And if you see `person` you know it's not a type. Being able to tell apart a class from a type parameter is useful because of [type erasure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure); classes exist at runtime but type parameters are removed from the code during compilation. (This applies moreso in Java than in Typescript, because in Java *only* type parameters are erased, whereas in Typescript interfaces and type aliases are also erased. But the convention comes from Java and similar languages, so it has stuck.)

Most likely, the default letter to use is `T` because it stands for "Type", then just like in mathematics it's conventional to use consecutive letters for multiple variables representing the same kinds of thing, so `S`, `T`, `U`, `V` are common. Also, `K` is often used for a generic key type and `V` for a value type associated with it; in some cases `E` is used for the type of "elements" in a collection.

Comment: Just to add - it's rare but occasionally you can use something more than letters for generic types. E.g., if you have `interface Converter<IN, OUT>`. A lot of times UPPER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES is used for those. But those cases are still rare.

Comment: Sure; it's also not too unusual to see `T1`, `T2`, `T3` like the numbers are mathematical subscripts. Whenever something is convention, there are alternative conventions! In your example I would normally write `Converter<S, T>` where the names can mean "source" and "target" as a mnemonic.

Comment: There's no reason not to be explicit in the signature to help other programmers.  `Converter<TSource, TDestination>` would be much more helpful.

Comment: Looking at VLAZ's example, I wouldn't know if IN and OUT were instances or generic definitions.  That's the primary reason why when most language can provide more explicit type usage, they use T<usage>  eg  Converter<TIn, TOut> although that's not a good example either because reusing Tin, TOut everywhere isn't much help to what the generic parameters are meant for eg `AssignRelationship<TIn, TOut>` or `AssignRelationship<TParent, TChild>`.

Comment: @ErikPhilips The fact that one is the source and the other the target is likely made explicit by some method or constructor signature like `methodName(S source, T target)`. The reason not to use longer names is only convention; you could write `TSource` and `TTarget` if you follow that convention, or `S` and `T` if you follow the more common convention that type parameters are single capital letters.

Comment: @kaya3 my point was T, S are ambiguous if used all over the place in code, that is the code is less readable.  Instead of ambiguity, I recommend programmers use more specific names if possible.  *You* may program however you wish, I'm talking in an objective manner for future readers/programmers.

Answer (score 7):

> I noticed most tutorials/courses/articles use T,U... as the name of generic types. Why exactly, why not assign normal names instead?

Mostly because they are mundane and poor examples.

As I mention below, It's much better practice to prefix something with T instead of just saying `T` *in most cases*.  `Array<T>` being prime example of one that is truly open.  If you were to say, write your own version of [.Net's Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-5.0) which holds Key Value Pairs, then you could see why you could be more explicit in the following examples of it's *interface*.

```
Dictionary<T,U>

// or

Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
```

Excerpt from my own answer of a very similar question:

[In Typescript what does `<T>` mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49622045/in-typescript-what-does-t-mean/49622066#49622066)

> `'T'` is going to be a type declared at run-time instead of *compile* time.  The `T` variable could be any non-declared variable (I couldn't find a reference, but I would assume any valid set of characters that could be used for a variable names).  Similarly in [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), if the type `T` represents is not a value type but a more complex type (class) or interface, it could be named/declared as `TVehicle` or `TAnimal` to help denote a valid type for future programmers (and could be considered best practice because just `T` is not intuitive). I prefer `TSomething` because I know that uppercase T means a generic type.  `WSometing` or `ASomething` is also valid, but I just don't prefer it.  (Microsofts APIs are almost always [TContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679506(v=vs.113).aspx) or [TEntity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696460(v=vs.113).aspx) for example).

> > You can explain to me why in the Typescript documentation they put <T> instead of putting something more descriptive like <Identity> for example. Nothing and <T> for me is the same. Now does everyone use the <T> like fools, or did I miss something?

> *These are all going to be assumptions in the following.  I do not know neither the team who designed the typescript generic system nor the team who wrote the documentation.*

> At the root level of generics is the ability to use `T` as *any possible type* (not to be confused with typescript `any`).  Meaning `Array<T>` is the *interface* (for lack of a better word) and when we create a concrete type we replace `T` with a declared type:

> `Array<number>`

> So for the *interface* `Array<T>` what makes more sense than `T`?  I don't know.  I do know that `T` has to be a Type (number, string, etc) so it makes sense to use `T` because it the first letter of the word *Type*.  I think `Array<Type>` would be really confusing and/or might even be invalid if *type* or *Type* became reserved or restricted (currently `type` has special meaning in certain contexts so it's also a poor choice) so avoiding those is a good choice.  Other languages ([C-sharp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods), [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)) also choose to use `T`, so switching between languages and being able to use the same term is advantageous.